# How can I write a letter inside a matrix between two rows and two columns?

Tags: matrices

I'm sorry I don't exactly know how to word the question,  a figure should show what I want.
Here's what I have
[image]

And here's what I want
[image]

M_f is a matrix whose components are not determined so I just want to write it's name inside the system.

Here's the code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{arydshln}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
\left[
\begin{array}{c;{2pt/2pt} c c}
 M_s &  & \\ \hdashline[2pt/2pt]
 & \matr{M}_f & \\
-\rho &  &
\end{array}
\right] \left[
\begin{array}{c}
\ddot{u} \\ \hdashline[2pt/2pt]
p_1 \\
p_2
\end{array}
\right]
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Thank you for your help.

And also if someone can advice me how to change the thickness of the dashed lines in the matrix, I tried changing the pt but what happens is that only the thickness change and not the the width. I can't post a third image since I only have 10 reputation points to show you the difference.

Comment: Please provide an MWE that starts from `\documentclass`

Comment: What does the `\matr` command do?

Comment: @Bernard Sorry I forgot to specify it, it's a function I made to bold out a letter, I made it when I started using latex and I got used to it instead of switching to the available functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nest an `array`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{arydshln}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
\left[\begin{array}{@{}c;{2pt/1pt}c@{}}
  M_s  & \\
\hdashline[2pt/1pt]
\begin{array}{@{}c@{}} \\ -\rho\end{array} & \mathbf{M}_f \\
\end{array}\right]
\!
\left[\begin{array}{c}
  \ddot{u} \\
\hdashline[2pt/2pt]
  p_1      \\
  p_2
\end{array}
\right]
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd avoid those ugly dashed lines, though:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
\left[\begin{array}{@{}c|c@{}}
  M_s  & \\
\hline
\begin{array}{@{}c@{}} \\ -\rho\end{array} & \mathbf{M}_f \\
\end{array}\right]
\! 
\left[\begin{array}{c}
  \ddot{u} \\
\hline
  p_1      \\
  p_2
\end{array}
\right]
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want the left matrix has three equal columns, you can add phantoms:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
\left[\begin{array}{@{}c|cc@{}}
  M_s  & \hphantom{-\rho} & \hphantom{-\rho}\\
\hline
\begin{array}{@{}c@{}} \\ -\rho\end{array} &
 \multicolumn{2}{c}{\mathbf{M}_f} \\
\end{array}\right]
\! 
\left[\begin{array}{c}
  \ddot{u} \\
\hline
  p_1      \\
  p_2
\end{array}
\right]
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It looks to me like the OP also wants the block with the **M**_*f* in to appear two columns wide, not just one?

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine Added

Answer (score 2):

Use the `\multirow` command from the `multirow` package to combine two rows for the matrix `M_f`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,multirow}
\usepackage{arydshln}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
\left[\begin{array}{c;{2pt/1pt}c}
     M_s  &                                 \\ \hdashline[2pt/1pt]
          & \multirow{2}{*}{$\mathbf{M}_f$} \\
    -\rho &              
\end{array}\right] 
\left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
    \ddot{u} \\ \hdashline[2pt/1pt]
    p_1      \\
    p_2
\end{array}
\right]
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

> [image]